# How to make a ToolBar which appear's on all the pages- PHP

Tags: php, html, toolbar

I want to Make a tool bar that appears on All the page's.

There are links of different Site on my webpage

I want that the tool bar appear's on every page when i click on the link.

```
http://www.mysite.com/page.php?=www.yahoo.com
```

so what ever link's that i click on the webpage of yahoo.com ( which is displayed on my site )
come's on like

```
http://www.mysite.com/page.php?=mail.yahoo.com/
```

I am using scrip like

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an about.com style toolbar, then you can use an HTML frame to do this http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html